# How to delete file after closing it in python?

Tags: python

What my code should do:
It creates a temp image and opens it in Windows, after that, when user close that image, it should be deleted from the folder. How can i do that?

```
        if (selected_langs != ""):
            os.startfile('temp' + '.' +  format)
            os.remove('temp' + '.' +  format)
```

I thought that would work, but it says that "file was moved or deleted"

Comment: *"startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status."* (from https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) - so you are trying to remove the file while it is still open

Comment: @UnholySheep
 So, it`s not possible to do that? I have searched in google about it, no result were found

Comment: You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) if you want to wait for the process to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a comment from [UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep), you'll need to check whether the file is closed or not. For example, do this:

```
import os
import time

selected_langs = "lang"
format = "txt"
waiting_time = 1  # seconds

def is_open(fname):
    try:
        f = os.open(fname)  # raises IOError when file is open
        f.close()
        return False
    except IOError:
        return True

if selected_langs:
    fname = f'temp.{format}'
    os.startfile(fname)
    while is_open(fname):
        time.sleep(waiting_time)
    os.remove(fname)
```

Untested code tho, as I don't have windows.

Answer (score -1):

Check if file exists, then delete it:

```
import os

if os.path.exists("demofile.txt"):
    os.remove("demofile.txt")
else:
    print("The file does not exist")
```